# Drupal theme for specific page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, themes, drupal-themes

Suppose that website is: http://www.mywebsite.com width Drupal Garland theme on all pages.

How to enable another theme and set it as default on a page like http://www.mywebsite.com/video ?

Blocks can be added on specific pages, but can templates done the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`ThemeKey`](https://drupal.org/project/themekey) module.

**From the module information:**

> ThemeKey is meant to be a generic theme switching module. It allows you to switch the theme for different paths and based on object properties (e.g. node field values). It can also be easily extended to support additional paths or properties as exposed by other modules.

Comment: Hi @ITChristian, [`Drupal`](https://drupal.org/project/drupal) 8 has not been released. Thus, the `ThemeKey` module maintainers have not created a Drupal 8 version of the module yet. However, there is currently a Drupal 6 version (which I have personally used successfully) and a Drupal 7 version. Upgrading from one major version of Drupal to another major version of Drupal (e.g. 7 to 8) would typically require updating all of your third-party modules.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the modules listed in this thread seem to work as of 2024 with D9 and D10 :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Page Theme module](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_theme) to achieve exactly that :
The Page Theme module is a simple and easy module to use which allows to use different themes than the site default on specific pages.

Features :

Assign a theme to a single page or list of pages. (Set a page as a Drupal path)
Allow to use '*' character as a wildcard in Drupal paths.
Allow to arrange themes. (If pages are several defined, the first theme in the list will be used)
Allow to enable/disable a theme.
Drupal novice friendly.

as will as you can use :
Sections which has most of the same features as Page Theme, but adds a role based selection and a "php snippet" area to choose the theme.

but if you want to use different themes than the site default on content creating, editing, and viewing pages you can use 
[Content Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_theme) which allows to use different themes than the site default on content creating, editing, and viewing pages.